# Where can I find the exact Solc compiler version in Docker?

Tags: solc, solidity-0.8.x, docker

I am using Docker to compile my solidity contracts with the following commands.

```
Unable to find image 'ethereum/solc:0.8.18' locally
0.8.18: Pulling from ethereum/solc
60bfd3cb9459: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:2403ae4d8eb149701d6abcf1ce3ab6996f9114f79c541d6ad39586c83b9962e4
Status: Downloaded newer image for ethereum/solc:0.8.18
+ docker run -v /home/arbitrage-bot/contracts:/sources ethereum/solc:0.8.18 --allow-paths=/sources/solc -o /sources/abi --optimize --overwrite --abi --bin /sources/solc/Swap.sol
Compiler run successful. Artifact(s) can be found in directory "/sources/abi".
+ IFS=.
+ read -ra name
+ goext=.go
+ abiext=.abi
+ binext=.bin
+ docker run --rm -v /home/arbitrage-bot/contracts:/sources ethereum/client-go:alltools-latest abigen --abi /sources/abi/Swap.abi --pkg=api --type=Swap --out=/sources/api/Swap.go --bin=/sources/abi/Swap.bin
```

When I attempt to verify my deployed contract on https://etherscan.io/sourcecode-demo.html
Entering `0.8.18` this as the compiler version I get

> Fail - Unable to verify. Invalid or not supported solc version, see
> https://etherscan.io/solcversions for list

I was looking here: https://github.com/ethereum/solc-bin/blob/gh-pages/bin/list.txt but not a just `0.8.18` version and serching for `60bfd3cb9459` does not yield any result.

My question is how can I get the commit hash for the culled down Docker image?